# ejb 3.1 Discard stateful session bean

Tags: ejb-3.1

I'm currently programming against a junit test (school assignment)
The Task is to create a stateful session bean which handles job assignments

The submitAssignments method should discard the session bean so that the   junit test works

```
    jobManagementBean.submitAssignments();
    // check if the bean was discarded after submitAssignments() was
    // called successfully!
    try {
        jobManagementBean.getCache();
        fail(NoSuchEJBException.class.getName() + " expected!");
    } catch (NoSuchEJBException e) {
        // Expected
    }
```

How can I discard the bean?

Comment: @Remove(retainIfException=true)

Comment: @sherif: I needed exactly the same! ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply `@Remove` annotation over a method in the stateful bean, the container will remove the bean after the completion of that method.

> **Annotation Type Remove :** Applied to a business method of a stateful session bean class. Indicates that the stateful session bean is to be removed by the container after completion of the method.